# Using Make command from Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'm attempting to run the command make dev in Windows Powershell to setup Docker containers.  I added the path to the make.exe file to System Variables and then restarted my computer.  However when I try to run make in Powershell it gives me the error: make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Any help in getting the make command to work correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you see the path you added if you run: `$env:path.split(";")` in the PS window?  What does it print if you run `where.exe make.exe`?

Comment: if I type in $env:path.split(";") in the PS windows it gives me the right path. The where.exe make.exe command gives an error.

Comment: Maybe try running Process Monitor to create a trace. I would trace the launching of Powershell to see the Process Start before running make.exe. You can see the environment for the Powershell process start to check the environment and the maybe see the search path in action.

Comment: So I added new-item alias:make -value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe' to my powershell profile and ran make dev but it gives me this error : make: *** No rule to make target 'help'.

Comment: Actually nevermind that error was because I wasn't in the right directory